Can I expect to find taxis at Kunming Changshui Airport at 2 am?
Kunming Changshui is a high-volume airport so probably the answer is yes.  But I would like to hear from someone who knows.

There's a large taxi queue there, so I would expect if there is an incoming flight there will be taxis.
You could also call a Didi but finding the pickup point at Changshui can be challenging if your Mandarin is weak.
Personally, I would not worry about it. 99.9% sure there will be taxis and if the 0.1% happens you can walk outside the airport and grab a Didi.

I posted a new question asking about the DiDi pickup at Changshui https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/189574/where-is-the-didi-pickup-at-kunming-changshui-airport?noredirect=1&lq=1

Yes.  I was just there, at 2:30am on a Thursday.  Numerous planes were arriving and there was a vast, fast moving, queue at the taxi stand.
