Where is the DiDi pickup at Kunming Changshui Airport?
Google Maps shows where taxi parking is at Changshui, but does not show anything about DiDi at the airport.
One answer at Can I expect to find taxis at Kunming Changshui Airport at 2 am? suggests the DiDi pick up point at Changshui airport can be hard to find if your Mandarin is not good enough.  Mine probably is good enough to ask people there where the pick up is, and to follow Chinese signage for it. But I will arrive at the very late end of a long flight, so would like to locate it in advance.

There is a DiDi pickup area by the main entrance to the main terminal, near the Taxi stand, but not at the same place.  Inside the terminal, as you approach the main entrance, there is good signage.
The white vans in the picture posted above are not DiDis.
I will say that at 2am, on a weekday in July, there were many fewer English speakers than you would find in Larger cities in China.

Thanks for coming back to tell us!

I found this link [screenshot below] on the airport's website that could help you locate if you are good at reading maps. Let me know, if you are not, I can explain you further.
Hope it helps.



Could you add a screenshot or something? Chinese websites are incredibly slow to load overseas (thanks Great Firewall).

Screenshot added

Thanks.  Please explain a little more.  I can read what this says about parking lots, rental cars, and taxis.  But I do not recognize 滴滴 here.

You’re right, seems there’s no dedicated place for the DiDi. As mentioned in the text, DiDi cars need to follow the same route as other taxis for pickup/drop off. I am attaching one more picture taking from Google maps. Hope you could read the Chinese text for taxi stand.

@NaveedAhmed Thanks again.  There is a lot about taxis in the picture and the text.   I still do not see where either one says anything about DiDis,

Maybe draw a circle or some arrows on the map. That way it would be helpful for those who don't speak/read Mandarin, too. Also, maybe indicate which terminal this is for - I'd imagine Changshui might have more than one terminal.

@FreeMan That picture is by the main terminal.  I believe the vans in the picture are limos.  They are not DiDis.
